# Can I get the old Parental Controls back?

Tags: parental-controls, screen-time

I just upgraded my OS from High Sierra to Big Sur, and I hate the new "Screen Time" instead of Parental Controls.  I LOVED using the parental controls as a way to block/limit my kids' computer use; I had a kids account where I set "bedtime" to be the entire day, and when they wanted to use the computer, I would sign them in for 15 or 30 or 60 minutes at a time. They got automatically logged out when their time was up.

Is there any way to do this on Big Sur?  It seems like screen time limits app use, but it doesn't limit the time that the kids' account can be logged in.  And right now it seems like it doesn't do a perfect job of limiting apps.  Is there anything I can do or any outside software I can install to get back to the system of manually approving each block of time that the kids want to use the computer, like the old Parental Controls?

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to get it back as of macOS Catalina. Apple has removed Parental Controls completely and has forced their users to use Screen Time.